# Sum to infinity of a spinner with 3 colours

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

Hey I'm stuck on a question which I think uses geometric series to solve, its for probability. The question is:

When a spinner is spun, the outcome is one of 3 colours, green, blue, or red. On anyone of the spins, the probability of each of those outcomes is pG, pB and pR respectively. Note that pG+pB+pR= 1. If the spinner is spun n times, what is the probability there is at least one blue outcome and one green outcome in the n spins.

My approach to this question is to find the probability of no blue and no green (2/3) then find the union (1/3 i think?, not sure on this) I did P(E) + P(F) - P(EnF) which is 2/3 + 2/3 - 3/3?? I don't know what to do from here though. I think I take the sum to infinity of (1/3)n ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a variant of the [Coupon Collector Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem)

$G$=there is no green in n spins

$B$=there is no blue in n spins

$P(G\cup B)=P(G)+P(B) - P(G\cap B)$

Now:

$P(G)=(p_B+p_R)^n$ (only blue and red in n spins)

$P(B)=(p_G+p_R)^n$ (only green and red in n spins)

$P(G\cap B)=(p_R)^n$ (only red in n spins)

and what we want is $1-P(G\cup B)$

(the opposite of both green and blue means that either of them is missing)

Comment: If I do that I get P(G) = (2/3)^n same for P(B) and then P(GnB) is (1/3)^n, so 1-P(GuB) = 1-1^n?

Comment: you cannot simplify that way... $(\frac{2}{3})^n$ is not $\frac{2}{3^n}$

Comment: Where does 2/3^n come from? There's brackets so wouldn't the exponent go to the numerator and denominator?

Comment: Also I am assuming that each probability is even, I was not told whether it was 1/3, so if I have no numbers to work by should I just use symbols as you have above?

Comment: Sorry, I might not understood your question. But 1-1^n seems to be wrong. BTW, you were the one who said first P(G) = (2/3)^n. I never mentioned that in my proof

Comment: Ahh sorry i confused myself. However for the actual question as no numbers for each probability are mentioned, should I just use the proof you have provided? Because I cannot come up with a numerical value as I don't know whether or not the spinner is evenly distributed.

Comment: yes, just write the answer in terms of $p_G, p_B$, and $p_R$